# How to get audio from a sensor for an Arduino

Tags: sensor, microphone, electret

I am working on an Arduino project that requires recording sound that is playing and flashing LED strips to go with whatever is playing in the air.  Currently I am using a sensor called the [KY-038](https://tkkrlab.nl/wiki/Arduino_KY-038_Microphone_sound_sensor_module) but I am unsure how to get audio from it or if it is even possible to get actual audio from it instead of just volume.  Basically what I want is some help getting the correct sensor and a guide or some directions on how I can turn the data from the sensor into something that I interpret on an Arduino.

Comment: Your link gives an example that shows how to make an LED glow brighter the more _sound_ the microphone _hears_. Have you tried that code together with your microphone?

Comment: You get audio from its Analog Out (AO) pin.

Comment: @HarrySvensson Ok I guess I didn't do a good job explaning.  I want it to flash brighter the more sound that plays, but I also want it to change color based upon the pitch of the sound.  So if a low pitched sound plays it will flash a different color than a high pitch sound.  Is it possible to do that with the sensor in the link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audio detector you have chosen is IMO not viable for your project needs.
The [KY-038](https://easyeda.com/normal/KY_038_Microphone_sound_sensor_module-7189f5cb17f041c48c57c5e5daaec42e) is a very simple sensor and from it's schematic (shown below) you can see that the gain is adjustable but with no pre-amplification to the analog output. The potentiometer in the main adjusts the threshold for the level detector, though it also has a gain effect for the Electret microphone (which has an inbuilt FET). Unfortunately the gain and output impedance of the Electret are tied, and this makes it a very poor candidate for providing good audio input to the Arduino A/D without an external pre-amp/buffer.

[image]

The op-amp in the KY-038 is an [LM393](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm393-n.pdf) and if you examine the schematic in detail you can see that you can make the circuit somewhat into an analog amplifier with an offset adjust ...however it's none ideal. Put a 50k Ohm resister from A0 to ground and a 100k Ohm from D0 to A0. You can then adjust the potentiometer to get 2.5 V on the D0 output and use this as the analog signal.

I don't recommend you do this, but would recommend you buy a more suitable audio mic/amplifier module ($2-3) such as that sold by many Ebay suppliers based on the [MAX4466](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX4465-MAX4469.pdf). The volume control actually works on this module and it has quite reasonable sensitivity!

Assuming you get to be able to get the audio you require, providing conversion to enable you to understand both amplitude and frequency components can best be done by implementing an FFT on the Arduino. 
If this is your first foray into FFT I recommend you use a bouncing ball project such as that [provided by Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/piccolo/code). This uses the same MAX4466 based microphone amplifier and may represent a good starting point for you to learn.

If you want to roll your own FFT and A/D code, then you will need to be able to run your A/D at a high continuous conversion rate. I don't recommend that you go above the maximum 9.6kHz conversion rate you get on the Arduino. Nyquist Theorem says that at that 9.6kHz sampling rate, the highest frequency component you can resolve is 4.8kHz.
If this is not enough bandwidth for you then you will need to increase the A/D conversion rate by altering the ADCSRA register. The prescaler for the A/D is 128 by default, you can read the [ATMega328 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_datasheet.pdf) 28.9.2 to learn more. The higher the conversion rate the more problems with noise you will have and this will impact the number of bits you can rely on for amplitude.

The last comment is that in the question you say you want to record the audio. This implies that when you play it back you want to understand it. ...yet another reason to drop the KY-038 and get a better mic/preamp module with good gain and linearity.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called a *microphone*.  Those put out tiny signals roughly proportional to the instantaneous sound pressure.

Typical microphones put out from less than a mV to a few mV.  You therefore need to amplify the raw microphone output by about 1000.  That's not too hard to do with two opamp stages each amplifying by about 32.

AC couple the result onto the output of a resistor divider that makes 1/2 the supply voltage of your microcontroller.  Then feed this voltage into a A/D input.  The rest is firmware.

If you only care about the volume of sound, not the actual sound, you can do the volume detection in a analog circuit and feed the result into the A/D input.  The advantage of this is that you can sample the A/D at a much lower rate.

Still, just sampling the A/D at, say, 50 kHz, then doing everything after that in firmware is a reasonable approach.  Even if you just wanted volume at maybe up to 20 Hz bandwidth, that can be done in firmware from the 50 kHz sample stream.

Comment: "_If you only care about the volume of sound, not the actual sound, you can do the volume detection in a analog circuit and feed the result into the A/D input. The advantage of this is that you can sample the A/D at a much lower rate._" -- Do you mean that he should make an envelope detector?

Comment: Is it possible to just find a microphone for the Arudino that doesn't require using an op-amp or anything?

Comment: I think you mean up to 20 kHz bandwidth for a 50 kHz A/D conversion rate (and not 20 Hz). However, 20 kHz is far beyond any of the simple microphone/amplifier modules available. I seriously doubt the OP would need anything beyond 10 kHz making 20 kHz A/D conversion rate more than adequate.

Comment: @Jack: He probably doesn't need 20 kHz bandwidth.  But since he didn't specify the application, I kept the answer general.  The 20 Hz I mentioned was for the volume bandwidth (AM demodulated audio), not the audio stream itself.

Comment: @OlinLathrop ...the OP directly pointed to pitch ...so needs frequency resolution.

Comment: @Jack: I just re-read the question, and it says nothing bout pitch.

Comment: @OlinLathrop. It's in his first comments ....so correct it is not in the question, but clearly from the comment what he wants to do.

Comment: @Jack: Comments aren't for content.  You really can't expect people to read all the comments to get information about the question.  You should be able to skip over comments, so I usually do.

Answer (score 0):

In order to change colors with frequency, you need to split the audio signal to several (3?) frequency bands and have each band control a different color. To do this, you need 3 parallel [band pass filters](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_4.html), say one tuned to bass frequencies controlling the red LEDs, one on mid controlling the green and one on high controlling the blue (if we assume you have an RGB strip). I'm quite sure the analog output from your sensor can't drive this though and I suspect you need some amplification or buffering in your signal path. Then you could get these 3 outputs to your analog ins or to the bases of transistors controlling the current to the LEDs.